What's going on with the plumbing under my bathroom sink?
https://imgur.com/a/ppYpX3B
I'm wanting to replace my bathroom vanity but the amount of foam around the plumbing is making me nervous as I have no idea why it's there.
Is there something going on here that I need to be wary of? Or will I really not know until I remove it?

What's going on with the water dripping from the hot supply line?  Also, why is the cold supply line on the left side?

It's a nothingburger.   That is just cheap spray foam insulation (expanding... expanding more than the person installing it thought).
It was put there to keep insects/rodents out or to gain a little r-value.    Just slice it out with a utility knife.   It will come off in chunks once you get going.   Then do whatever you need.
